# Перекодирование файла из Windows ANSI кодировки в utf-8

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, кодировка, перекодировка

Появилась такая проблема во время разработки программы на C++. Программа должна прочитать содержимое текстового файла input.txt, обработать и записать в другой файл output.txt. Текст внутри файла input.txt имеет кодировку cp1251. Чтобы программа корректно работала нужно перекодировать файл в UTF-8. Ни как не могу разобраться, как это сделать. Может уже есть какие-то готовые функции? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нет такой кодировки unicode, есть, например, utf-8 или utf-16-le

Comment: Прошу прощения. Ошибся( Нужно перекодировать в utf-8

Comment: ASCII коды в utf-8 е же самые, т.е. перекодировки не будет. Если символы не в этих пределах U+0000 - U+007F это уже не ASCII.

Comment: ascii строгое подмножество utf-8 (то есть у вас вход уже utf-8 если он действительно ascii). Может вы имеете в виду  Windows ANSI code page (к примеру, cp1251 на русской Windows)?

Comment: Зачем при копировании файла вообще думать о кодировках? Открываем в bin-mode и побайтно копируем.

Comment: jfs, да именно, CP1251. Я могу конечно же его пере кодировать с помощью Notepad++, но нужно, чтобы программ сама это делала, может есть какие нибудь идеи по реализации?

Comment: avp, да для копирование так, Но я не копирую, а считываю, обрабатываю (меняю исходный текст неким образом, типо шифрования) потом сохраняю его уже в другом файле))

Comment: Покажите ваше решение и что в нем не работает.